# Database views or tables for queries - design best practices

Tags: sql, database-design, view, relational-database

What are you design best practices for database exposure to application access (mainly queries)?

IMHO, we should **almost always prefer views over tables** for queries. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) delineates their strengths only, drawbacks are omitted. Moreover it perfectly fits [CQRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) principle. We can use views for queries and stored procs for modifications. In such procs we have more control over what and how to save.

Some possible drawbacks:

- view maintenance cost as it enlarges project's code base
- more complex ORMs mapping configuration which can impede developer's productivity

Last question: if views are really better, why I feel they are underutilized in most projects that use RDBMS for storage?

Comment: Why sprocs for writing? Not DRY most of the time. Most of time can get away with constraints (check, foreign key, null, unique, pk), and auto-updatable views

Comment: auto-updatable views are ok, but sometimes there are constraints such as a modification can affect only data from one table within a view comprised of several tables.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, depending on how much hardware you have available to you, is to set up  a second server that users are allowed to run queries against.  You would set up replication from your backend server to this "playground" server and replicate data to the playground at certain points throughout the day, effectively refreshing the data periodically if users were to mess it up.

I don't think that older versions of some RDBMS views can be indexed which can hurt performance.  I think this is less of an issue today though.

Comment: ok, but it still doesn't solve the problem of schema drifts in db physical layer. Without views it can be more costly to change application code after db schema needs to be changed.

Comment: It's just a matter of duplicating schema changes on what are supposed to be two identical servers though right?  Mind you I'm not saying views aren't valuable, they certainly are.  But if the schema changes wouldn't that necessitate a change in the view definitions anyway?

Comment: If the schema changes, view definitions are likely to change, but you have the possibility not to change exposed views (for consumer applications) - only the way the views are constructed has to be changed. It's like table query interface for consumer applications.